# How to start running test files on my application in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I finished developing an application ,and I have a ready `test.js` files for the client side and for server side. The tests are in [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) ,[Chai](http://chaijs.com/) and [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/). I don't know how to connect the application files with the test files and how should I run them.
I appreciate any help/guidelines.

Comment: did you try to navigate into your project directory with the cli and then use the 'mocha' command?

Comment: @I'll try that but what is the command to write?

Comment: Start by reading and following the [getting started](https://mochajs.org/#getting-started) section of the mocha documentation that you linked. It shows the commandline command and how you run it via npm script.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to have a tests folders in root directory(where your main js file is) and put test.js in there. Then just execute: **mocha tests --recursive**

This command will run all the tests.